# HTTP protocol that doesn't use request or response headers

Tags: http

My question is, which version of the HTTP-protocol doesn't use the request and response headers. I am taking a course and this is one of the pre-eaxm test questions (to brush up your knowledge). The answer is HTTP 0.9 but I haven't been able to find any documentation on this. Are there request and response headers in HTTP 0.8 then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3 HTTP 0.9 spec states that:

> This document defines the Hypertext Transfer protocol (HTTP) as
> originally implemented by the World Wide Web initaitive software in
> the prototype released. This is a subset of the full HTTP protocol,
> and is known as HTTP 0.9.
>
> This restricted protocol is very simple and may always be used when
> you do not need the capabilities of the full protocol which is
> backwards compatible.

**Source:** http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html

HTTP 0.9 appears to be a subset of the full protocol and thus I doubt that versions 0.8 < exist as HTTP 1.0 is the first implementation. (The 0.9 is used to denote that this isn't the full version)

Wikipedia states:

> HTTP/1.1 is a revision of **the original HTTP (HTTP/1.0).**

**Source:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Technical_overview

HTTP 0.9 is a restrictive version of the HTTP protocol (hence why it doesn't use request or response headers) that is designed to be easy to use.

**Note:** I am not an expert on this matter and am just going by what available documentation I can find so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 0.9 was first documented version (1991). So, there will be seldom people who will be able to tell about version prior to that

Documentation for version .9 is [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html)

Further, it will help you if you first try to search on google, you may get a lot of explanation.